How to hide ids from URL
I have a button on my site, that will take you to somewhere else in the same page. But that id is appearing in the URL. And I don't want it to be shown. So in my URL there is the main part / site name / the id that I don't want to show.
here is the URL picture: till the hostinger.com is the main part after / is the site name / #and the id:

I found that I should go to settings and in permanlinks I should change it to Post name but I used it already so I didn't got anywhere. I didn't find any wordpress support email address either.

That's a basic facet of how web browsers work, you pass the ID as fragment in the address bar and it knows to scroll to that point. It would be possible to bodge your way around it with an event handler, but

That's not specific to WordPress, so would be best asked on a different Stack
Interfering with the browser's page history is bad UX

